# Where is the version specified in Ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using AppVersion.getVersionNumber() to get the version number of my Ionic app. But where does this number come from?

The problem is that when I run the app on a smartphone through devapp, I get a different version number depending on what OS I have…

- iOS (on an iPhone 6): 1.0.2
- Android (on a Samsung S10): 1.0.4

Searching around for "version" in my source code, I find this in config.xml (in the root):

```
<widget version="1.0.3" … >
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but it is the currently delivered version of the app.

I'm using Ionic 4.10.0

Answer (score 0):

`AppVersion` cordova plugin reads the app details from the native code of the application.

So the version values that you see, are configured in the native IDE's.
Check these files in your respective platform folders..

`ios/App/App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` the key to look for in this `MARKETING_VERSION`

`android/app/build.gradle` the key to look for in this `versionName`